# use content of rows of dataframe as function inputs

Tags: r, dataframe, function, csv, multiple-columns

this should be simple?
so I have a custom function that works. I can input the name of data frame (crick) and which trial I want to run within it for example *speed.hd1(sv.j20.19, 1)*

```
speed.hd1 <- function(crick, trial){
  hd.time <- which(crick$time == head.data$hd1[trial])
  hd.vel <- crick$velocity[hd.time]
  return(hd.vel)
}
```

I want to use the numbers in each row of 2 particular columns (same name as function variables) as inputs in the function . Each `crick` goes with a particular `trial` as you can see from the data [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj8Jg.png)

the function `speed.hd1` gives the velocity at a particular that is specified by hd1 [velocity and time are in this data set here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYVcT.png) bc each crick velocity data is stored in a different file (as u see from 2nd link) I have to specify the crick in `speed.hd1`

and I want to make a new column in the dataframe with the results of the function

I have tried

```
crick.trial.sv$speed <- speed.hd1(crick.trial.sv$crick, crick.trial.sv$trial)
```

and

```
crick.trial.sv$speed <- speed.hd1(crick.trial.sv[1:25,3], crick.trial.sv[1:25,4])
```

which give **Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

Comment: It's difficult to understand your intent from the information you've provided. Please see here on how to create a good minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It seems like this could be simplified as a join or self-join operation, probably a one-liner. It's hard to know, however, as you shared a picture of data instead of reproducible input, you didn't share desired output, and some of the columns you use (`time` and `velocity`) aren't included in your screenshot.

Comment: @GregorThomas I have updated with a bit of clarity of what's going on with function/data. any thought?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.